# Google Reader App that fetches the full article content

Tags: google-reader, rss

I've been searching and hoping to find an app for Android that syncs up with Google Reader and has one key feature.  The feature I'm looking for is the ability to fetch the entire news article that you're reading.  Certain websites (CBC News in Canada for example) allow you to "read more", however this opens a new browser instance to view the rest of the article. I'm looking for the ability to have that content scraped inside the application for reading.

Reeder for iPad has this functionality. Does anyone know of an app for Android that does the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After posting the question here, I contacted all the different developers of google reader apps on the android market that I could find.  So far only one developer has answered whose app does exactly what I'm looking for, but 1 is good enough!

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.droidlab7.reader.pro

I've tried it out on a Gawker Media RSS feed (Deadspin) and CBC Sports News, works perfectly and fetches the full article, no more annoying browser pop up!  In the top right corner there's a button that executes the "mobilizing" functionality, which is the scrape that I was looking for.   If/when I hear back from other developers I'll post it up more links.

Answer (score 5):

[NewsRob](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.newsrob.pro&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5uZXdzcm9iLnBybyJd) Pro also fetches the full feeds.  You can choose between Readability and some other methods. It works but I'm not a huge fan, it was just the best one that I found (I didn't try D7 though).

Comment: Noticed this app hasn't been updated since June 2010.. Also couldn't figure out how to download the full feed in line, so I returned the pro version

Comment: @BrianGarson The NewsRob Pro app is just an unlocker, that's why it hasn't been updated often. The actual app is very actively under development with regular updates, see also its Google Group: https://groups.google.com/group/newsrob

Answer (score 1):

Hi I personnaly use [gReader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.noinnion.android.greader.reader) which has an integrated browser that lets you load the article inside the reader ! no need to open a new browser window, it's a no-friction process !

Comment: Beauty this one works great as well, I think I prefer it to the droidLab7 reader pro.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try [Feedly](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devhd.feedly) on the play store ;)

Comment: This doesn't seem to hook up with google reader (at least I can't figure out how to)

Answer (score 0):

My app [Full Feed](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rizvn.fullfeedvn) does 50% of this and is free. It can fetch full content of RSS feeds on Android, but has no Google Reader sync yet.